# Formtastic Collection Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, formtastic

I need to sort a collection for formtastic by their state, wether they are selected or not.

My setup looks similar to the following

```
# user.rb
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colours
end
```

´

```
# colour.rb
class Colour
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  scope :ordered_for, lambda { |user|
    all.sort_by { |s| include? user ? 1 : 0 }
  }
end
```

´

```
# _form.html.haml
= semantic_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.input :colours, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Colour.ordered_for(current_user)
```

`ordered_for` returns a well sorted Array. In fact formtastic destroys this order afterwards and sorts the colours by `id`.

What's a good approach to supres that behaviour? Is there any smarter way to achieve an order by selection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
Colour.ordered_for(current_user).all
```